# Share ASP.Net Membership and Roles among web and Desktop applications

Tags: asp.net

Microsoft has provided us with ASPNETDB that takes care of Membership and roles.

Can I use and share Membership and Roles across Web, Intranet and Desktop applications?

We have some C# desktop applications and some ASP.Net Web applications. Currently we are using Windows authentication for desktop applications and Forms authentication for web applications. I was wondering if we can simply use ASP.Net Membership and roles feature for all applications.

Please advise what is your opinion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all of your logic for authentication and authorization in one place, then you can have your website expose a service that the desktop application can call to verify users. This service could leverage the providers you have written for your website.

This would require the desktop application computer to have a network connection, but unless you plan to store a copy of the aspnetdb database locally, it would need a network connection anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net membership from a desktop application. You need to make sure your target framework is not a client profile, and add a reference to System.Web